# dy(x)/dx Notation Question

Tags: notation

Suppose $y$ is a function of $x$, i.e. $y=f(x)$. (just univariate)
Would both of the following notations for the first derivative of $y$ (with respect to $x$) be correct and usable?

1. $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$
2. $\dfrac{dy(x)}{dx}$

The second one is just to emphasize that $y$ is a function of $x$, even without which it seems obvious. But this notation is still okay to use, correct?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Sometimes you do see it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered by the first comment.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is yes, it's quite common to omit the dependent variable but including is just as correct.

Comment: It is more common to omit the dependent variable.  So you will often see $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $y'(x)$ or $\frac{d}{dx} y(x)$, while $\frac{dy(x)}{dx}$ is rarer though still reasonable and $\frac{dy}{dx} (x)$ might confuse some people